# Yii Scope not being passed into CListView

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to pass this model scope into my CListView

here is the scope in my Comment model

```
public function scopes()
    {
        return array(
            'lastestComment'=>array(
                    'alias' => 't',
                    'select'=>array('t.*,t2.*'),
                    'join'=>'JOIN `comments_posts` AS t2',
                    'condition'=>'t.id=t2.commentId',
                    'order'=>'t.createDate ASC',
                    'limit'=>'5'
                )
        );
    }
```

in my view i have this

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider(Comment::model()->lastestComment());
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                        'itemView'=>'_view', //view file location
                    ));
```

in the view, then i call `$data` i can only get values in the `comments` model and not from the `comments_post` table in my scope join. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to make this much complicated to acheive what you want,

YII is always simple

in `model`

```
public function relations() {

        return array(
            'posts' => array(self::HAS_MANY, "CommentPosts", array("commentId" => "id")),
        );
    }
```

in `view` you can get the data in `comment table` as

```
$data->column_name
```

and data in the `comment_post table` as

```
foreach($data->posts as $postings){
   $postings->column_name;
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between using relations and scope? isn't relations like using `defautScope`? my understanding is, by doing it this way. everytime i call the `comment` model, it will query both tables. even though i just need data from 1

Comment: hmmm `$data->posts->postId` doesn't work. but when i `print_r($data-posts)` i get this `Array ( [0] => CommentsPosts Object ( [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [postId] => 33 [make_code] => 02 [model_code] => 21 [year_made] => 2014 ....`

Comment: dont just try with print_r what Yii does is when you call the value it executes the query for performance it does so. so just try to print_r($data->posts) you'll get those values to

Comment: when i do `$data->posts->postId` i get nothing tho. but print_r($data->posts)' i get that array

Comment: you have to get them in foreach since it is HAS_Many Relation. see answer edited

Comment: @user2636556, instead of `$data->posts->postId` you use `posts.postId` (at least it works in GridView).